# How long ServiceStack takes to get start?

Tags: servicestack

I'm building a client/server game with WCF, unfortunately because of compatibility problem, I met huge challenge when porting my RESTful server end to linux(mono). So dudes ask me try ServiceStack instead of ask questions everywhere :p.

Now the question is, I know nothing about this framework. How long it takes to get start?
 How much it needs to change my original WCF code? Changing client end to fit REST instead of WebService is a big work, so definitely I don't want ServiceStack is too hard for me.

Any advise? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting your code from WCF to ServiceStack will mean a complete overhaul. No part of the service layer is the same. It is not to be taken lightly.

If the work of converting the client to REST is itself too much work, then this will be too much.

That being said, I would encourage you to look at it anyway. ServiceStack is considerably faster to develop with once you are familiar with it, it is a much more flexible framework, and it is drastically faster than WCF (especially at serialization).

I can't think of a single thing in WCF I prefer to ServiceStack.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you said it's a overhaul for service part, is that include Contracts implementation(say, MyService), or just wcf parts(interface/host)? Thanks again!

Comment: The whole thing. Service, interface, host, DTOs. It is nothing like WCF

Comment: Get it. I'd better fix my bugs for now and consider it in next project. Thanks for your guide :)